# trinio sql equivalent for utc date time

Tags: sql, datetime-format, utc

I wanted to check if there is trinio equivalent of UTC date time like we have in sql server getUTCDATE(). I basically want current date time but in utc timestamp format for Trinio sql query.

Comment: Did the [docs](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html) not help ?

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the online availbable functions, you could use:

timezone_hour(timestamp) ? bigint#
Returns the hour of the time zone offset from timestamp.

now() ? timestamp(3) with time zone#
This is an alias for current_timestamp.

date_add(unit, value, timestamp) ? [same as input]#
Adds an interval value of type unit to timestamp. Subtraction can be performed by using a negative value:

and do (untested, so I am  not sure if a `-` (minus) sign is missing ):

```
SELECT date_add(hour, timezone_hour(now()), now());
```